# How to fix APP has stopped in android studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, web, webview

I have been creating a webView APP using Android Studio, I have tried building the project, the build ends up successful, but when I try running the APP via an emulator the APP crashes, Bun when I click on run to see what happens I get this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.newvemo.newvemo, PID: 4628
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.newvemo.newvemo/com.newvemo.newvemo.SplashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
        at com.newvemo.newvemo.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

More Specific the error is

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
        at com.newvemo.newvemo.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:19)
```

Here is my SplashScreen.java

```
package com.newvemo.newvemo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        Thread splashThread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(300);
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        splashThread.start();
    }
}
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.newvemo.newvemo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is the activity_splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="363dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"
        android:padding="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:max="100"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:progress="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried the followings but still a problem persists

1. Invalidate and Restart
2. Commenting `getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Help me how to solve such scenario so that my app runs well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could be using NoActionBar theme. Check that and if your theme is NoActionBar then you don’t need to call `getSupportActionBar()`

Comment: Thanks @Lookyus, I have removed getSupportActionBar() and everything works fine now

Answer (score 0):

Before
`getSupportActionBar().hide()`
you should call
`setSupportActionBar()`

Because `getSupportActionBar()` is Null by default and you couldn't call `hide()` and it throws NullPointerException

Comment: Hi Alireza Khosroabadi, I try adding setSupportActionBar(), but it needs an argument, what argument should I pass there?

Comment: A toolbar. which you should add at the top of the activity

Comment: you should pass Toolbar to it